# Linux filename check if exist and delete

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I have some problem in Shell scripting.
So I have to write a script that find every file in a directory with this string: "gom". So i found all of them. After I need to cut it off, and compare that the remaining filename is exist. If exist i need to remove the file that contains the string.

Example: there are 5 files: algomb, gomba, alb, algomba, alba.

I need to find the filenames with "gom". algomb, gomba, algomba.
After it i need to cut the "gom". And a remaining filenames is exist I need to remove the file with "gom" string.
So after the cutting "gom" there will be 5 files: alb, ba, alb, alba, alba
So there are two files that is extist: alb, alba....I need to remove the following files: algomb, albomba.
After it the will be 3 files: gomba, alb, alba.

Sorry for my bad english.

I can find, I can remove, but I cant compare the filenames.

Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash 
sz="gom"
talal=`find . -type f -name "*$sz*" -exec basename {} \;`
ossz=`find . -type f -exec basename {} \;`
c=`echo ${talal%%:*}${talal##*:}`

for c in ossz; do       
if [ ! -d ]; then
    echo "This is a directory"  
else    
if [ -f ];
then
    find .-type f -name "*$sz*" -exec basename {} \;  
else    
    echo ${talal%%:*}${talal##*:} 

fi  
fi
done
```

So this is works. This `echo ${talal%%:*}${talal##*:}` is give back the filename without "gom". But I cant compare these values with `find . -type f -exec basename {} \;` results.

Sorry for my bad english.
Can sombody help me?

Best regards, Richard

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way, without `find`.

```
shopt -s globstar
for gom_file in **/*gom*; do
    # Skip non-regular files
    [[ -f $gom_file ]] || continue
    # Delete the file if the gom-free file exists
    [[ -f ${gom_file/$sz//} ]] && rm "$gom_file"
done
```

Using `find` is slightly less efficient, since you need to fork a new shell for each file:

```
find . -type f -name "*gom*" -exec bash -c 'echo rm -f "${1/gom/}"' {} \;
```

Run this to test that it outputs the `rm` commands you want to execute, then run it again with `echo` removed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use those bash features:

- array (declare -a)
- hashtable (declare -A)
- regex ( ${a/b/c} ${a//b/c} )

Here is an example as a general idea:

```
#!/bin/bash 
sz="gom"

declare -a ta
declare -A ossz

i=0

while read -r -d $'\0' ff
do ta[$i]=$ff
   i=$((i+1))
done < <(find . -type f -name "*$sz*" -print0)

while read -r -d $'\0' ff
do ossz[${ff##*/}]=1
done < <(find . -type f -print0)

for ff in "${ta[@]}"
do subff=${ff/$sz/}
   subff=${subff##*/}
   if [ _${ossz[$subff]} = _1 ]
   then echo "$ff"
   fi
done
```